# Can I use localhost:7979 for amp test and one or more different builds created with buildkit?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, civibuild

After running `amp config` and `amp test`, I successfully created a `drupal-clean` build using `buildkit` and `civibuild` on `localhost:7979`, and added a bunch of extensions, etc.

I turned off my Ubuntu 19.04 laptop, and booted up the next day. However, at `localhost:7979` I received a lock error message. So I reran `amp test` to check everything, and the test passed. `amp test` also uses `localhost:7979`.

Now, at `localhost:7979` I see

```
Error: Expected GET or POST value 'exampleData=foozball' Error: Failed to write /home/joe/.amp/canary/data/DSEGrMDEi4ocNQRuBOo4IbE2e73MaT8M/example.txt Error: Failed to remove /home/joe/.amp/canary/data/DSEGrMDEi4ocNQRuBOo4IbE2e73MaT8M/example.txt
```

I ran `curl http://localhost:7979/index.php` and get the same result as immediately above.

I ran `sudo lsof -i :7979` and get this result:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 16634     root    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
apache2 16635 www-data    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
apache2 16636 www-data    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
apache2 16637 www-data    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
apache2 16638 www-data    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
apache2 16639 www-data    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
apache2 16716 www-data    7u  IPv4 507012      0t0  TCP localhost:7979 (LISTEN)
```

In the results above, the first process is running as `root`, not `www-data`. Do I just need to kill that process? Something else?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out the real problem is that I created a build using `mysql_ram_disk` instead of `mysql_dsn` in `amp config`- meaning the mysql database is in RAM, and of course disappears when I turn off my laptop :) .